# Categorizing data based on group and according to a separate column

Tags: r

What I'm asking here feels pretty complicated so bear with me as I try my best to explain it.

This spreadsheet is data on bird nests. Each nest has a specific identifier, ID_NIU. For this identifier, there can be anywhere from 1-3 rows which each represent a specific egg. The amount of rows corresponds to the count, which just tells me how many eggs are in each nest. Don't worry really about what PVC is, it shouldn't matter.

Egg_order is exactly what it sounds like; it's the order the eggs were laid in. If the value is 9, that means that we don't know the order. I need two things to happen in the most efficient way possible.

1. I want a column made that shows one of three things. Let's call the column Status. I want Status to either be the word non, complete, or estimated.
   a) if all of the egg_order in a ID_NIU is 9, give it the value: none
   b) if all of the egg_order shows a number, like 1, 2, or 3 (so basically a complete set), give it the value: complete
   c) there can be an instance where only the THIRD egg is known. if that happens, give the value: estimated (this happens for ID_NIU 426 for example)
2. For the estimated ID_NIU (based on the categorization above), I want the two 9 values to be replaced by 1 or 2. Basically, I just want to assign them a random order.

Here is my data

```
> dput(nests1994)
structure(list(ID_NIU = c(421L, 421L, 421L, 422L, 422L, 423L, 
423L, 423L, 424L, 424L, 425L, 425L, 425L, 426L, 426L, 426L, 427L, 
427L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 429L, 429L, 429L, 430L, 430L, 431L, 431L, 
431L, 432L, 432L, 432L, 433L, 433L, 433L, 434L, 434L, 434L, 435L, 
435L, 435L, 436L, 436L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 438L, 438L, 438L, 439L, 
439L, 439L, 440L, 440L, 440L, 441L, 441L, 441L, 442L, 442L, 442L, 
443L, 443L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 445L, 445L, 446L, 446L, 446L, 447L, 
447L, 447L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 449L, 449L, 449L, 450L, 450L, 451L, 
451L, 451L, 452L, 452L, 452L, 453L, 453L, 453L, 454L, 454L, 454L, 
456L, 456L, 456L, 457L, 457L, 457L, 458L, 458L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 
460L, 460L, 461L, 461L, 461L, 462L, 462L, 462L, 463L, 463L, 463L, 
464L, 464L, 464L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 466L, 466L, 466L, 467L, 467L, 
467L, 468L, 468L, 468L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 470L, 470L, 470L, 471L, 
471L, 471L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 474L, 474L, 474L, 
475L, 475L, 475L, 476L, 476L, 476L, 477L, 477L, 477L, 478L, 478L, 
478L, 479L, 479L, 479L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 481L, 481L, 481L, 482L, 
482L, 483L, 484L, 484L, 484L, 485L, 485L, 485L, 486L, 486L, 486L, 
487L, 488L, 488L, 488L, 489L, 489L, 489L, 490L, 490L, 490L, 491L, 
492L, 492L, 492L, 493L, 493L, 493L, 494L, 494L, 494L, 495L, 495L, 
496L, 497L, 497L, 497L, 498L, 498L, 555L, 555L, 555L, 556L, 556L, 
556L, 557L, 557L, 557L, 558L, 558L, 558L, 559L, 559L, 559L, 560L, 
560L, 560L, 561L, 561L, 561L, 562L, 562L, 562L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 
564L, 564L, 564L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 566L, 566L, 567L, 567L, 567L, 
572L, 572L, 572L, 573L, 573L, 573L, 574L, 574L, 574L, 575L, 575L, 
575L, 576L, 576L, 576L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 579L, 
579L, 579L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 595L, 595L, 597L, 597L, 597L, 598L, 
598L, 599L, 599L, 612L, 612L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 614L, 615L, 615L, 
615L, 616L, 616L, 617L, 617L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 620L, 620L, 620L, 
622L, 622L, 622L, 624L, 624L, 624L, 625L, 625L, 625L, 626L, 626L, 
626L, 627L, 627L, 627L, 628L, 628L, 628L, 629L, 629L, 629L, 633L, 
633L, 633L, 661L, 661L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 663L, 663L, 663L, 664L, 
664L, 664L, 665L, 665L, 665L, 666L, 666L, 666L, 667L, 667L, 667L, 
668L, 668L, 668L, 669L, 669L, 669L, 670L, 673L, 673L, 674L, 674L, 
674L, 675L, 675L, 675L, 676L, 676L, 676L, 677L, 677L, 677L, 679L, 
679L, 679L, 680L, 680L, 681L, 681L, 682L, 682L, 682L, 683L, 683L, 
683L, 684L, 684L, 684L, 685L, 685L, 685L, 686L, 686L, 686L, 687L, 
687L, 687L, 688L, 688L, 688L, 689L, 689L, 689L, 690L, 690L, 690L, 
691L, 691L, 691L, 692L, 692L, 692L, 791L, 793L, 793L, 793L, 794L, 
794L, 794L), Egg_order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 
9L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), PVC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VNRB", "VNRB", "VNRB", "VRNB", "VJNZ", "VJNZ", 
"VBRN", "VBRN", "VBRN", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VRJA", "VRJA", 
"VRJA", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), volume = c(61.32180296484, 59.19889832633, 61.23059740728, 
56.63892668014, 51.205468528125, 56.00474267058, 57.351199948, 
55.54398620844, 55.70776780426, 59.72462114472, 59.37718398586, 
60.587478792225, 56.43498962184, 62.26391957376, 65.6381047725, 
60.0863309088, 64.85091746762, 60.069900631215, 59.4870511833, 
57.0005821184, 54.02542528228, 64.73294631594, 66.3508141931, 
62.32245834917, 59.02536867768, 66.01653978486, 60.083474171985, 
59.684503147035, 60.074662267125, 66.157670868, 64.14003788994, 
64.72516250826, 65.43246736143, 64.76946298056, 59.525282639625, 
64.83564670912, 63.10304890812, 59.162532552, 58.56437083104, 
58.51350718936, 60.47152094199, 59.46823641825, 56.529403558675, 
62.59313732544, 62.86182498192, 57.4115839709, 67.488455384, 
70.67781620074, 69.066635590395, 61.4648739568, 61.793295785165, 
57.141971818575, 57.86003450088, 66.8841551616, 54.2789360685, 
57.372537480805, 54.7688704779, 52.69147903188, 65.717390741625, 
62.0012941321, 65.46154452084, 67.54235220404, 68.589406082885, 
61.3698407482, 63.22307904, 73.52276685129, 67.7605920462, 64.9948112, 
67.39168007286, 59.96388195, 53.75359412352, 61.2940024137, 62.371936324995, 
58.27667400405, 61.00711558812, 60.68288712456, 57.22440302628, 
63.7912474123, 60.71915094122, 56.17566934848, 61.03055081916, 
54.48216125544, 66.59971341696, 62.914325579595, 60.06312844672, 
63.18295147084, 64.13649043698, 54.61024964874, 58.69608972288, 
60.093902811735, 55.80205524, 66.35080327284, 64.56965497461, 
61.61846995898, 58.962280801605, 54.114679926855, 51.32463260472, 
66.763949034375, 66.60433698016, 57.9960342297, 65.65621056552, 
63.50880453696, 59.93124997824, 57.28414633702, 68.946491941355, 
69.53883617025, 60.591651012, 66.51464159232, 62.83111160808, 
59.31893121786, 66.012559966525, 65.39124391634, 61.63458903486, 
64.527880462335, 65.626394311215, 62.28965754018, 70.66749192426, 
63.43547903014, 64.813554775305, 63.30184211559, 70.84510569583, 
65.07164575845, 62.649526678335, 62.07063053623, 62.97169774328, 
58.15387242406, 53.775184290885, 56.15800014276, 63.84106319499, 
58.0287792375, 55.39166100811, 67.06270568448, 64.243137862495, 
61.79094929648, 59.278741074, 57.54892103096, 54.4025191125, 
68.63881395584, 65.99016072992, 61.71771694458, 56.032400073, 
59.67369896548, 55.55819890452, 59.74163316768, 64.678925498375, 
59.632117506, 58.352016509955, 60.27802279574, 58.15564421248, 
54.715232384505, 50.918826189105, 47.311723228, 60.24653229088, 
62.9644540122, 58.28735951144, 67.67941018152, 69.600416585815, 
63.089844045435, 65.63935543424, 65.14029179418, 56.9031766875, 
63.86502197092, 68.50758708486, 66.796303493015, 62.558885508, 
62.68239015272, 59.33579351744, 55.87331866844, 57.779988655095, 
57.4011795375, 68.10503423888, 62.19287447292, 62.29393628778, 
59.54119382656, 62.45667881766, 55.88073186822, 57.19354986962, 
60.62398562056, 53.222328389025, 64.17951754275, 63.46964125062, 
54.25258541904, 53.85227447392, 62.667268102495, 65.9379849576, 
57.10713872136, 57.16095228242, 62.99889140907, 56.223702755685, 
60.56377100622, 62.599569594775, 60.431980928505, 64.63537220204, 
56.8203240696, 59.08446543104, 58.51081609896, 64.82126705664, 
66.14591297517, 58.5345118041, 69.089203199115, 70.813911929975, 
63.129352317125, 62.864854839, 61.69528927, 62.66206973912, 60.8490630645, 
62.4062419139, 57.63741735136, 60.30546945984, 56.07545557164, 
59.79910741368, 63.51030603488, 64.244819090745, 63.75469472867, 
63.14277341512, 62.42052636864, 55.59848049998, 59.7551696205, 
55.20343376232, 60.1519184288, 63.59769165096, 55.71145827984, 
61.30230509475, 56.592753090795, 58.582661261135, 62.62695713592, 
57.883156922925, 63.30930401034, 70.73778793872, 63.12040753536, 
67.936748153665, 62.77154643396, 56.5502664375, 56.676188799945, 
58.8897719179, 65.12593779432, 59.877119390625, 57.5611109065, 
60.50238159481, 51.421804965475, 60.702761718885, 57.857797190545, 
51.76334378277, 54.79479091296, 58.036980255275, 64.08885388248, 
58.9371852075, 48.065806272, 58.67924387256, 60.84988863732, 
55.348644357, 60.809342925895, 56.891942571875, 55.16386692882, 
64.568934378585, 64.46865534354, 58.50186242472, 63.15022238365, 
57.54034615239, 55.58259809634, 58.5784229184, 60.76172518406, 
48.88389467288, 62.93741556969, 65.16504696727, 58.68311406489, 
69.20272240048, 67.510966264695, 63.60102202762, 58.3678358505, 
62.78118931648, 50.330023359885, 62.36847890792, 61.459224858675, 
58.101076579725, 59.849752446945, 60.89355981824, 70.38978991616, 
64.78264300106, 63.851029018155, 56.76600004895, 56.36582838225, 
57.656775733025, 57.07565196264, 62.78661705624, 58.80025808496, 
62.473741510995, 52.27790378878, 61.65878807979, 69.9430447975, 
62.6025867725, 70.091062468875, 55.31320436328, 57.091324193955, 
59.88525953314, 62.81526020564, 58.817878683495, 62.600767032615, 
58.88047597916, 52.271088452865, 56.4597812485, 56.49555113631, 
58.59997224246, 60.56042671782, 63.62604866394, 54.689279244925, 
64.08885388248, 58.9371852075, 48.065806272, 58.67924387256, 
60.84988863732, 55.348644357, 60.809342925895, 56.891942571875, 
55.16386692882, 64.568934378585, 64.46865534354, 58.50186242472, 
58.5784229184, 60.76172518406, 48.88389467288, 58.3678358505, 
62.78118931648, 50.330023359885, 59.36245744586, 54.203960064, 
46.80082663263, 53.7591748284, 56.45379150432, 58.18760585216, 
51.57368944, 61.17471364797, 55.666216654855, 63.638574522745, 
62.859327856115, 55.71589759736, 62.194594993445, 60.1319744625, 
63.2669776704, 52.67023014204, 53.95264575354, 52.19798075712, 
64.12727076352, 58.722978252375, 61.129745915095, 60.35801243148, 
53.570630477, 60.42489898518, 58.83334580928, 58.579377003125, 
53.63492716368, 62.198328240205, 59.16052306314, 63.03268283832, 
53.4038938596, 59.3680844275, 64.01347375464, 53.247602726, 58.656773926835, 
62.406351950215, 60.794167405875, 57.26072539408, 58.41489611248, 
59.89059546628, 58.27766415192, 55.752501203565, 52.67023014204, 
53.95264575354, 52.19798075712, 68.84950003552, 72.3285771465, 
69.97203251224, 58.01968982825, 59.19871381875, 51.0058844818375, 
55.871632176, 65.005463693925, 61.884602267345, 59.36399202272, 
55.61013283256, 63.119620683, 65.19505402688, 65.256547524625, 
60.287946825, 63.546970479, 55.83345829936, 57.83224146336, 62.76964734468, 
63.3625642155, 61.089794891755, 67.23069090625, 59.524399629225, 
61.86069234304, 58.52247185176, 60.14631038544, 55.03887100416, 
57.43869855744, 60.64346718786, 56.9845087625, 60.2844366375, 
57.7861645641, 54.31168897016, 52.9873440048, 53.708649730785, 
65.219353008, 57.88846182528, 54.873862054245, 53.072090597655, 
78.369980834265, 57.516393056295, 61.3480561875, 53.67391420878, 
57.29314740352, 54.1968033555, 52.85290720594), Year = c("1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", 
"1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994"), count = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -415L), groups = structure(list(
    ID_NIU = c(421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 
    429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 
    439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 
    449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 
    460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 
    470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 
    480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 
    490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 555L, 
    556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 564L, 565L, 
    566L, 567L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 
    594L, 595L, 597L, 598L, 599L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 
    617L, 618L, 620L, 622L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
    633L, 661L, 662L, 663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 
    670L, 673L, 674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 
    683L, 684L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 
    791L, 793L, 794L), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:5, 6:8, 
        9:10, 11:13, 14:16, 17:18, 19:21, 22:24, 25:26, 27:29, 
        30:32, 33:35, 36:38, 39:41, 42:43, 44:46, 47:49, 50:52, 
        53:55, 56:58, 59:61, 62:64, 65L, 66:68, 69:71, 72:74, 
        75:77, 78:80, 81:82, 83:85, 86:88, 89:91, 92:94, 95:97, 
        98:100, 101:103, 104L, 105:107, 108:110, 111:113, 114:116, 
        117:119, 120:122, 123:125, 126:128, 129:131, 132:134, 
        135:137, 138:140, 141:143, 144:146, 147:149, 150:152, 
        153:155, 156:158, 159:161, 162:164, 165:167, 168:170, 
        171:172, 173L, 174:176, 177:179, 180:182, 183L, 184:186, 
        187:189, 190:192, 193L, 194:196, 197:199, 200:202, 203:204, 
        205L, 206:208, 209:210, 211:213, 214:216, 217:219, 220:222, 
        223:225, 226:228, 229:231, 232:234, 235:237, 238:240, 
        241:243, 244:245, 246:248, 249:251, 252:254, 255:257, 
        258:260, 261:263, 264:266, 267:269, 270:272, 273:275, 
        276:277, 278:280, 281:282, 283:284, 285:287, 288L, 289:290, 
        291:293, 294:295, 296:297, 298:300, 301:303, 304:306, 
        307:309, 310:312, 313:315, 316:318, 319:321, 322:324, 
        325:327, 328:329, 330:332, 333:335, 336:338, 339:341, 
        342:344, 345:347, 348:350, 351:353, 354L, 355:356, 357:359, 
        360:362, 363:365, 366:368, 369:371, 372:373, 374:375, 
        376:378, 379:381, 382:384, 385:387, 388:390, 391:393, 
        394:396, 397:399, 400:402, 403:405, 406:408, 409L, 410:412, 
        413:415), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -151L), .drop = TRUE))
```

If you have questions please ask.

Comment: when you say `there can be an instance where only the THIRD egg is known`, is it non-NA value

Comment: Also, not clear when you say `if that happens, give the value: estimated`

Comment: @akrun kind of? that non-NA value needs to be a 3. So, if you look at ID_NIU, you'll see that it has a 9, 9, and then 3. In this case only the 3rd egg is known. It can also have the order 3, 9, 9. All that it needs is just one row to have the 3 in it.

Comment: @akrun I want a column made based on the criteria. So based on the criteria, I would want a column with the word estimated.

Comment: i understand the first two cases i.e. returning 'none' and 'complete'.  if there is a 3 with 9, what would you want to return

Comment: @akrun are you saying if there's just a singular 9 and a 3? technically that can't happen so you could return invalid.

Comment: For ID_NIU 426, there are two 9's and one 3.  so, what would be the corresponding value for the new column

Comment: Do you need `nests1994 %>% group_by(ID_NIU) %>% mutate(new = case_when(all(Egg_order %in% 9) ~ 'none', all(Egg_order %in% c(1, 2, 3)) ~ 'complete', all(setdiff(Egg_order, 9) == 3) ~ 'estimated' )) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this `egg_status` (ad 1), `estimated_Egg_order` (ad 2):

```r
nest1994 |> 
  group_by(ID_NIU) |> 
  mutate(egg_status = case_when(all(Egg_order == 9) ~ "none",
                                any(Egg_order == 9) ~ "estimated",
                                TRUE ~ "complete")
         ) |> 
  mutate(estimated_Egg_order = if_else(egg_status == "estimated" & Egg_order == 9, row_number(), Egg_order)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 30 × 8
   ID_NIU Egg_order PVC   volume Year  count egg_status estimated_Egg_order
    <int>     <int> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>                    <int>
 1    421         1 NA      61.3 1994      3 complete                     1
 2    421         2 NA      59.2 1994      3 complete                     2
 3    421         3 NA      61.2 1994      3 complete                     3
 4    422         1 NA      56.6 1994      2 complete                     1
 5    422         2 NA      51.2 1994      2 complete                     2
 6    423         1 NA      56.0 1994      3 complete                     1
 7    423         2 NA      57.4 1994      3 complete                     2
 8    423         3 NA      55.5 1994      3 complete                     3
 9    424         9 NA      55.7 1994      2 none                         9
10    424         9 NA      59.7 1994      2 none                         9
11    425         1 NA      59.4 1994      3 complete                     1
12    425         2 NA      60.6 1994      3 complete                     2
13    425         3 NA      56.4 1994      3 complete                     3
14    426         9 NA      62.3 1994      3 estimated                    1
15    426         9 NA      65.6 1994      3 estimated                    2
16    426         3 NA      60.1 1994      3 estimated                    3
17    427         1 NA      64.9 1994      2 complete                     1
18    427         2 NA      60.1 1994      2 complete                     2
19    428         1 NA      59.5 1994      3 complete                     1
20    428         2 NA      57.0 1994      3 complete                     2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `if/else` or `case_when` to create the column 'Status' based on the conditions

```
library(dplyr)
nests1994 <- nests1994 %>% 
 group_by(ID_NIU) %>%
 mutate(Status = case_when(all(Egg_order %in% 9) ~ 'none', 
                    all(Egg_order %in% c(1, 2, 3)) ~ 'complete', 
                    all(setdiff(Egg_order, 9) == 3) ~ 'estimated' )) %>%    
 mutate(estimated_Egg_order = replace(Egg_order,
      Egg_order == 9, seq_len(sum(Egg_order == 9)))) %>%
 ungroup
```

-output

```
> nests1994 %>% filter(Egg_order == 9)
# A tibble: 195 × 8
   ID_NIU Egg_order PVC   volume Year  count Status    estimated_Egg_order
    <int>     <int> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>                   <int>
 1    424         9 <NA>    55.7 1994      2 none                        1
 2    424         9 <NA>    59.7 1994      2 none                        2
 3    426         9 <NA>    62.3 1994      3 estimated                   1
 4    426         9 <NA>    65.6 1994      3 estimated                   2
 5    430         9 <NA>    59.0 1994      2 none                        1
 6    430         9 <NA>    66.0 1994      2 none                        2
 7    448         9 <NA>    61.0 1994      3 estimated                   1
 8    448         9 <NA>    60.7 1994      3 estimated                   2
 9    476         9 <NA>    60.2 1994      3 estimated                   1
10    476         9 <NA>    63.0 1994      3 estimated                   2
# … with 185 more rows
```

Comment: this is correct but for the estimated status columns, I want the 9 and the 9 to be replaced with 1 and 2 arbiturally. it doesn't matter which is which, but for calculation purposes later on they can't be the number 9

Comment: Not clear.  when you say the 9 and the 9 to be replaced with 1 and 2.  Did you meant if there are more than 9s, then it is the sequence of that

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're asking. If the column is estimated, there should be two 9s. If that's the case, one of the 9s should be replaced with a 1 and the other should be replaced with a 2. don't worry about it too much, I found an answer above that worked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution first groups by ID_NIU, then uses some logic to determine the rest. It also replaces the earlier values in estimated columns, and includes some extra `row_number` and `rev(row_number())` to catch potential values outside of 1, 2, and 3:

```r
nests1994 %>%
  group_by(ID_NIU) %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(
    all(Egg_order == 9) ~ "None",
    Egg_order == row_number() | Egg_order == rev(row_number()) | Egg_order %in% c(1, 2, 3) ~ "Complete",
    first(Egg_order) == 9 & last(Egg_order) != 9 ~ "Estimated",
    TRUE ~ "Miscellaneous"
  ),
  Egg_order = if_else(status == "Estimated" & Egg_order == 9, row_number(), Egg_order))
```

Comment: this code is really close to being right. But, what ends up happening is that for the 9,9,3 situations, the status column said estimated for the replaced 9 and 9, but said complete for the row with the 3. Since they're all part of the same ID_NIU, the status column needs to be the same.